# Add additional fields in the payment form in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have tried to add additional fields in the payment form in Magento 2, but I have not succeeded. I have reviewed several manuals on this, but I can't find a definitive one.

What I want is to add 2 fields, in the first one that allows choosing the type of document as dropdown and the second field is displayed to complete the information with the chosen document number.

If anyone has managed to implement this type of requirement, I would greatly appreciate your help.

[image]

I have tried to add additional fields in the payment form in Magento 2, but I have not succeeded. I have reviewed several manuals on this, but I can't find a definitive one.

Comment: Do you need to save these fields data in order table or any custom table?

Comment: Yes, I need to save this data in the order record of the administrator and the client.